# Where do I store spare tire?

Tags: mercedes-benz, spare-tire, c230k

I have a 2003 Mercedes-Benz C230k coupe, and I'm not sure where the spare goes or how to fit it

Where do I store the spare tire on my 2003 Mercedes-Benz C230k coupe?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a picture, if this is what you are asking.  I'm not exactly sure what you are asking...  where do you store the spare tire?  Where I assume you found it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under the trunk floor? It's a doughnut.